# Adding Methods on the Fly to Object

Tags: javascript

I hope this can be done in Javascript.

> I Have something like this:

have something like this:

```
var MYOBJECT = {
method1: function(){//some cool},
addMethodToObject: function (a_new_method){
//whats need to be here to add the
 method passed in "a_new_method" to MYOBJECT ?
}

}
```

The idea is to call:

```
MYOBJECT.addMethodToObject(function otherMethod(needThis){return needThis;});
```

and now MYOBJECT has the Method passed as a new Method, and I can do something like this:

```
MYOBJECT.otherMethod('say Hi');
```

will output

> "say Hi"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much like others have stated, just pass in an anonymous function as an argument to your addMethodToObject function.

```
var MYOBJECT = {
    method1: function(){ ; },
    addMethodToObject: function (methodName, method) {
        this[methodName] = method;
    }
};

MYOBJECT.addMethodToObject("newMethod", function () {
    console.log("testing 123");
});

MYOBJECT.newMethod();
```

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested the answers above but all of them need to change the object from inside.
I needed something without changing the object from the inside and so I came up with this solution:

First create and instance of your object, then:

```
yourObject.yourMethodName = function(methodParam1, methodParam2) {
    doWhatYouNeed;
};
```

Then execute as:

```
yourObject.yourMethodName(methodParam1, methodParam2);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to do that. You don't need to, though, just assign to `MYOBJECT` directly:

```
MYOBJECT.otherMethod = otherMethod;
function otherMethod(needThis){
    return needThis;
}
```

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, you can pass around references to them just like any other object. And you can create new properties on a JavaScript object at any time, just by assigning a value to the property.

If you want to define a function for it, the function will have to accept both the function *and* the name you want it to have on the object, like this, which looks like this:

```
var MYOBJECT = {
    // ...
    addMethodToObject: function(name, func) {
        this[name] = func;
    }
};
```

That's because there's no reason the property and the function have to have the same name, and there's no *standard* way to get the name of the function from the function instance. (There are a couple of *non-standard* ways, but nothing defined by the standard.)

The syntax I used there may be unfamiliar. In JavaScript, there are *two* ways to access properties: Dotted notation with a literal name, and bracketed notation with a string. Examples are the clearest way to demonstrate it:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 42;    // Dotted notation with a literal name `foo`
obj["foo"] = 42; // Exactly the same thing, using bracketed notation and a string
var s = "foo";
obj[s] = 42;     // Again the same, because the string doesn't have to be a literal
```

...which is why `this[name] = func;` works; `name` is the string name of the property to add.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function test() {

  myObj = {
    addMethod: function( method, name ) {
      this[name] = method;
    }
  }

  myObj.addMethod( function() { alert( "foo" ) }, "fooMethod" );
  myObj.fooMethod();

}
```

See ya ;)

Comment: Yeaph, something like that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

simple u can just add a new method like u add a new property

```
obj["MethodName"] = function(){//ur Javascript statements}
```